# What characters are safe in cross-platform file names for Linux, Windows and OS-X 

Tags: filenames

Currently, I use a `YYMMDD-NAME+PAGE` name for most of my files. `NAME` has spaces converted to underscores.

I'd like to use the `YYYY-MM-DD` date format, but I am not sure how to separate it from the name. A `-` would look strange if the name started with a number. If I use a `_`, then it conflicts with the underscore representing a space.

What characters are reasonably safe in file names that would work here? I am on Linux, but I might share files with other people (Windows 7, Mac OS X).

Comment: … on Unix, Windows, an Amiga 1000?

Comment: Mostly modern Linux.

Comment: - symbol is safe to use on windows 7.. may be other modern operating system do same.. you can use minus symbol to separate..

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Summary:**

- Windows: anything except ASCII's control characters and `\/:*?"<>|`
- Linux, OS-X: anything except null or `/`

On all platforms it is best to avoid non-printable characters such as the ASCII control-characters.

**Windows**

In Windows, Windows Explorer does not allow control-characters or `\/:*?"<>|` You can use spaces. If you use spaces, you will often have to quote the filename when used from the command line (but GUI apps are unaffected so far as I know). Windows filesystem such as NTFS apparently store the encoding with the filename, but UTF-16 is standard.

Some parts of Windows are case-sensitive, other parts are case-insensitive.
It is easy to create distinct filenames like "Ab" and "ab" on a Windows NTFS filesystem. These names refer to separate files which contain distinct separate content. However, although the Windows command-prompt will happily list both files using `dir`, you cannot easily access or manipulate one of them using commands such as `type`. See below.

**Linux, OS-X**

In Linux and OS-X only `/` of the printable ASCII set is prohibited I believe. Some characters (shell metacharacters like `*?!`) will cause problems in command lines and will require the filename to be appropriately quoted or escaped.

Linux filesystems such as ext2, ext3 are character-set agnostic (I think they just treat it more or less as a byte stream - only nulls and `/` are prohibited). This means you can store filenames in UTF-8 encoding. I believe it is up to the shell or other application to know what encoding to use to properly convert the filename for display or processing.

**Conclusion**

So you could probably safely use something like `✣` (if it weren't so hard to type)

---

**Case-(in)sensitivity in Windows**

```
C> dir /B
Ab
aB
аB

C> type Ab
b
b

C> type aB
b
b

C> type аB
unicode homograph
```

Note that we cannot type the contents of the second file, the Windows `type` command just returns the contents of Ab instead. The third file would be distinct from aB on Linux also.

(Windows 10 NTFS).

Comment: All in all a good answer, but I'd refrain from using filenames in spaces. Escaping them properly in all contexts is more trouble than it's worth. Notice that Microsoft stopped using space in system directory names. If you need to indicate word boundaries in names, CamelCase works fine.

Comment: "C:\Program files (x86)" still exists in Win8 - is that not a system directory? I agree that spaces can cause problems.

Comment: It is, but it can be renamed to pretty much anything. Of course, a lot of programs will freak out if you rename it to "]:\foobar", but Windows refers to it as "%programfiles(x86)%" anyway.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Oops. Good point. What I should have said is that MS stopped using names with spaces for newly-invented system directories.

Comment: Something to really keep in mind here, linux system are able to consider uppercase and lower as distinct, whilst Windows considers them the same.

Comment: @thecoshman  +1,  this is very important and should be read by anyone asking this question.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch there are also "System Volume Information", "Documents and Settings", "All Users", "Recycle Bin"... And "My Documents", "My Videos"... although they're only a system-created directories. Actually if an app doesn't support spaces in filenames in this era I would throw it away rightaway

Comment: You'd be surprised how many programs suck at parsing. That's why there was no Windows 9.

Comment: Clarification for Mac OS, at least as of Catalina, you can create a file with `:` in the terminal, but it displays as a forward slash `/` in Finder and does not allow adding `:` through Finder.

Comment: TIL that emojis can be used as file and folder names  My data is about to get a whole new makeover ⭐

Answer (score 94):

While RedGrittyBrick's answer is technically correct, safety isn't the only issue: usability is also important. I think a better question is "what characters are good to use in a filename".

Some potential guidelines:

- **[0-9a-zA-Z_]** - Alphanumeric characters and the underscore are always fine to use.
- **`\/:*?"<>|`** and the **null byte** are problematic on at least one system, and should *always* be avoided.
- **Spaces** are used as argument separators on many systems, so filenames with spaces should be avoided when possible. Other whitespaces (e.g. tabs) even more so.
- **Semicolons (;)** are used to separate commands on many systems.
  **Semicolons and commas(,)** are used to separate command line arguments on *(some versions of?)* the windows command line.
- **`[]()^ #%&!@:+={}'~`** and **[`]** all have special meanings in many shells, and are annoying to work around, and so should be avoided. They also [tend to look horrible in URLs](http://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/web/cms/characters-avoid/).
- **Leading characters** to avoid:

  - Many command line programs use the **hyphen [-]** to indicate special arguments.
  - *nix based systems use a **full-stop [.]** as a leading character for hidden files and directories.
- Anything not in the **[ASCII set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii)** can cause problems on older or more basic systems (e.g. some embedded systems), and should be used with care.

That basically leaves you with:

## [0-9a-zA-Z-._]

that are *always* safe and not annoying to use (as long as you start the filename with an alpha-numeric) :)

Comment: The braces (`[]`) are part of regular expressions and have special meaning in the shell as well. But they are not as that bad to work with except some evil corner cases.

Comment: Hrm... I guess the same could be said about `()`, actually.

Comment: In zsh, characters that might be interpreted differently include `[]()^;`, so I think the right answer might actually be `[0-9a-zA-Z.,_-]` Comma could also possibly be excluded just because it's weird to see in a filename, although I can't think of an actual case where it would cause problems.

Comment: yeah, I removed them from the final list

Comment: @Phil_1984_: I had some inside the braces too : http://superuser.com/revisions/748264/1 :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for -- much better than the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: One may add that any non-printable ASCII characters (i.e., 0-31 and 127) should be avoided, too, though this is implicit in the final character set.

Comment: And what about `$`?

Comment: I don't think I'd include `.` in the list of characters that are "not annoying to use". Obviously there's potential for misinterpretation as an extension, etc.

Comment: If you're going to disallow spaces because they might be interpreted by the shell then you need to disallow semicolon ';' as well.

Comment: bronson: removed. @SteveBennet: an extension is just a convention. The "<filename>.<ext>" is just one string - the stop has no special meaning except what particular software gives it (e.g. it's basically just used as a short-cut for "open with <selected app>").

Comment: I know, but that doesn't change my view.

Comment: @SteveBennett: OK. Other than the hidden behaviour already noted in the answer, what actually makes the use of a period in a name annoying? I mean, can you give an example?

Comment: Well, a name like `foo.tar` would be annoying because if it was gzipped, it would become `foo.tar.gz` which would be misinterpreted.

Comment: @SteveBennet: So you're saying you should avoid the use of inappropriate file extensions (assuming `foo.tar` is not a tar archive)? I completely agree.

Comment: comma can be annoying, try `echo whereami > a,b,c` in Win10 command prompt window.

Comment: The comma `,` is not safe for anything that needs to use that path in a CSV. I can't think of a single CSV interpreter that can handle a path with a comma in it.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: I don't use windows. What does that do?

Comment: @HackSlash: this isn't about CSVs. CSVs don't contain paths, they contain strings. It's up to the interpreter how to use those strings. And CSV reader/writers *should* have the ability to write strings surrounded by quote marks (most that I've used do), in which case the problem is avoided.

Comment: @naught101: it creates a file named "a" containing the text `whereami ,b,c`

Comment: Wow. WTF. Does that mean that windows command line treats `,` as an argument separator?

Comment: What if you make a filename out of those characters and eventually get a dot-beginning filename like `.git`?

Comment: "Anything not in the ASCII set can cause problems on older or more basic systems" Even on some modern file-sharing systems like Google Drive or Dropbox, or on versions of Apple's HFS filesystem, the encoding of certain non-ASCII characters can get silently changed for you, causing files not to be recognized by their original name. This makes them unsafe for many uses.

Comment: Requiring an alphanumeric to start a filename leaves you with the only option being to prefix zeroes if you want a filename to sort before others.  Not the worst solution, but still a bit clunky `00-important.txt`

Comment: I don't think underscore(only) is allowed on linux => Try to give a file or a folder the name "_"

Answer (score 4):

You could:

1. replace current underscores with `#` (proofreader's symbol for space)
2. underscore to 'section' date from filename (or a second hyphen - easier to type)

Alt-1. initial-caps can replace spaces: `YYMMDD-HHMM-FileName.ext` or `YYMMDD-HHMM_FileName.ext`

Minimal characters for clear display, which auto-sorts with padded zeroes for Jan-Sep (& 1st-9th ea mo).

Answer (score 2):

The characters have largely been addressed by other people, though I will point out an additional aspect to consider. First, I'm addressing the choice of YYMMDD, which has two problems.

The first problem with YYMMDD is that it won't work for historic data. It will sort 1997 long after 2035, instead of before. Whether that's an issue may be dependant on how widespread you want to propagate the format.

The other issue with YYMMDD relates to the calendar reliance. While the Gregorian calendar is now the most popular one in the world, not everyone uses it or is aware of the day in its reference. Fortunately, the Gregorian *year* is generally known and accepted, even by those who use different years, but the month/day nomenclature can be meaningless. To be more portable, a format of
    YYYYDDD
where DDD is the day in the year, is more portable. However, for those of us who use the Gregorian calendar *that* is difficult because we generally are not aware of the day of the year. The MMDD format still is sortable, even if it means nothing to an individual, who themselves might create a date like 20221442 (Gregorian year and their month and day) or 20220047 (Gregorian February 16, the 47th day of the year), thinking they are complying with your format.

Continuing the theme of how widespread the format is to be used, a consideration needs to be made for the characters available around the world. The short dash '-' is available everywhere (?) because it is the minus sign, used globally. Underscore is more of a problem, even for some who use the Latin alphabet. They can normally get to it one way or another but it is not on every keyboard. In some alphabets, the underscore is a character or character modifier, so makes confusion. In many Persian languages, the underscore would be read as a kasheeda. In many alphabets, what we use an underscore for, they would use an overline: something hard to get on our keyboards. Most of the keyboards for technical people have the simple latin alphabet available on them (sometimes on the side of the key), so they can type the letters. But not always the underscore.

Comment: Oh, don't forget that everybody does not speak English.  I'd recommend you use Latin, it's a old, dead, scholarly language and is used extensively in scientific fields.  It also has the added benefit of using more endings and fewer words, so spaces are less often a problem.

Answer (score 1):

also note that: not only characters can be invalid, but also filenames (combinations of characters) can be invalid.

on windows, these filenames are invalid, because they are legacy device names:

```
CON PRN AUX NUL
COM0 COM1 COM2 COM3 COM4 COM5 COM6 COM7 COM8 COM9
LPT0 LPT1 LPT2 LPT3 LPT4 LPT5 LPT6 LPT7 LPT8 LPT9
```

even worse, this limitation is case-insensitive, so for example `Con` is an invalid filename.

even worse, you cannot use these reserved names as basename, so for example `Con.txt` is an invalid filename.

see also:

- [Get reserved file names in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561117/get-reserved-file-names-in-windows)
- [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces § Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions)
- [Peripheral Interchange Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral_Interchange_Program) uses these filenames as device names

a more well-known limit on filenames is the size limit of 255 bytes (not 255 unicode-characters).

See also:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-filename
- https://pypi.org/project/sanitize-filename/