# is it possible to add a directory containing ":" to a search path

Tags: bash

For bash the path separator for the environment variable `$PATH` is `":"`

So out of curiosity:

if a have a directory named
`$HOME/with:character`

Is there any way I can add it to the search path?

Please note that I think adding `:` to a filename is not a very smart idea, but I wanted to know if I could add such a directory to a search path if I ever encountered one

I tried with a backslash, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/with\\:character"
```

double `:` (`::`) doesn't work either

Comment: Don't use colons in file or directory names. See https://superuser.com/questions/358855/what-characters-are-safe-in-cross-platform-file-names-for-linux-windows-and-os for which other characters you should avoid too.

Comment: Thanks for telling me, But this is a hypothetical questions out of curiosity.
I would have expected, that `:` is not even allowed in a file / directory name.
 I  personally stick to lowercase letters, numbers and underscores whenever possible

Comment: On nix, afaik the only strictly 'illegal' character is `/` but `:` can be misinterpreted as a path separator too, so really should be avoided.

Comment: yeah. but is there any trick to add a path containing a  `:` character to a search path.

Is there any kind of escaping?

Again I would never use this in real life. but I'm curious

Comment: are you sure? On my Linux the `~` is expanded prior to assigning the value to `PATH`

So PATH contains `/home/gelonida/with\\:character`

If I wanted a `~` I had to type `export PATH=$PATH:\~/with\\:character`
(I'm using bash)

Comment: Well, for Bash I was wrong. It seems Bash handles the tilde when assigning this way (with or without `export`). `sh` on the other hand may not.

Comment: sh will definitely not expand `~`

Comment: In fact I will remove the `~` from my question. Though the question was tagged as `bash`, it might also be read by others. This is probably a good idea as it is not relevant for the rest of the question

Comment: What happens however is that sometimes users use a `~` in languages like `python`
This will fail except they use something like `os.path.expanduser("~/with:character")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to escape the colon.
This is impossible according to the POSIX standard.
PATH handling is done within the `execvp` function in the C library
where there is no provision for any kind of quoting.
This is the reason why including characters not in the
[portable filename character set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282)
is strongly recommended against.

From [SUSv7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03):

> Since `<colon>` is a separator in this context, directory names that might be used in PATH should not include a `<colon>` character.

See also [source of GLIBC execvp](https://github.com/zerovm/glibc/blob/master/posix/execvp.c). It uses the `strchrnul` function for processing the PATH components,
with no unescaping of any kind.

Your best bet is to rename the directory. If it really needs to have that name,
you can create a symbolic link and add that to your `$PATH`:

```
 $ cd /path/to/add
 $ ln -s a:b a_b
 $ PATH="$PATH:/path/to/add/a_b/bin"
```