# Is this the right way to iterate over components of $PATH?

Tags: linux, bash, path

For various reasons, I want to use an environment variable to pass multiple file paths to my script. I hit upon the idea of structuring the variable like `PATH` is, with colons to separate the entries.

After some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash), I came up with the following technique to iterate over the names:

```bsh
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=":"
# using PATH to demonstrate
for ITEM in $PATH; do
    echo hacking $ITEM which comes from $PATH
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

It appears to work properly, but I am a bit concerned:

- Manipulating `IFS` seems rather awkward and inelegant to me, and not scalable (what if someone else already uses `OLD_IFS`?).
- The output shows the colons in `PATH` replaced with spaces - has the value actually temporarily changed somehow, or is this only a display quirk?
- This appears not to do globbing if there is e.g. a `*` in the input variable; but is it properly secure? What other threats might I need to guard against?
- Then there's the issue of colons. While I understand that any character except `/` is technically legal in a UNIX directory or file name, I also understand that `:` is discouraged since it [cannot be escaped](https://superuser.com/questions/1634534/is-it-possible-to-add-a-directory-containing-to-a-search-path) for the purposes of PATH. However, I still feel like I'd prefer a fully general solution.

Did I miss a better option? Am I supposed to live with these sorts of things in a shell script? I'm much more accustomed to using application development languages like Python, which feel much more "regular" for lack of a better word.

Comment: "The output shows the colons in PATH replaced with spaces" – Because `IFS=":"` is still in effect and your *unquoted* `$PATH` expands to *multiple* arguments to `echo`; and `echo` prints it arguments separated by spaces, regardless of `IFS`.

Comment: Ah, it's actually being used by the shell to tokenize, not something specific to `for`. Of course.