# Is the tilde symbol okay to use in folder names? The filesystem is EXT4?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm archiving some of my Audio CDs to FLAC and I would like the album titles to include the catalog number and the location plus country, like so:

```
/Music/
  Laura Branigan/
    1982 - Branigan [19289-2 (250 772) ~ US 1985]
```

The catalog number already includes the dash (as you can see in 19289-2), so using that as a separator later on doesn't make sense. I was thinking about using the tilde `~` as a separator instead, to separate the catalog number from location/year.

Will that naming convention cause any trouble in the filesystem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What characters are safe in cross-platform file names for Linux, Windows and OS-X](https://superuser.com/questions/358855/what-characters-are-safe-in-cross-platform-file-names-for-linux-windows-and-os)

Comment: Your link mentions this: []()^ #%&!@:+={}'~ and [`] all have special meanings in many shells, and are annoying to work around, and so should be avoided. They also tend to look horrible in URLs.` however I'm not willing to use the tilde in CLI or URLs, and as long as the whole name of the folder is between double quotes `$ cd "Name of Folder With ~ Tile"` what could be wrong?

Comment: What other separator I could use instead of the dash ?

Answer (score 2):

In general in Linux `~` undergoes tilde expansion, which is suppressed by quotes (or other means of escaping like `\`). Since you have spaces in file names, you will use quotes anyhow, I gather. And you should do this by default anyhow. So it should be ok. Same as here:

```
$ touch "~"
$ ls -l "~"
-rw-r----- 1 tomasz tomasz 0 Aug  6 18:12 '~'
```